# Validate XML with VS Code

Tags: xml, validation, visual-studio-code, xml-validation

I was a Mac user with BBEdit & Co. Now I'm on Windows with VS Code. I'm looking for an easy solution to validate XML with VS Code. Is there an extension for this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can validate you XML online too

Comment: I know. But it would be great to have it directly in the tool. By the way, which online validator would you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is ["XML"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) extension (known as "XML Language Support by Red Hat") that does not require Java.

Old answer:

For validating XML Schemas in VS Code there is a package called [XML Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.XMLLanguageSupport).

Comment: downvote because this extension requires java, unlike XML Tools from Qub https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qub.qub-xml-vscode

Comment: Unfortunately, now it is deprecated. Also agree with Devin that disadvantage is that it requires JDK or OpenJDK.

Answer (score 13):

I just wanted to know if my xml syntax was valid, and I didn't want to have to install and setup Java.

XML Tools from Qub worked great for me, I highly recommend it:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qub.qub-xml-vscode

If you need to validate xml against a schema, some of the other more popular extensions might be better

Comment: How do you get it to actually tell you if your xml is valid? I don't see that option in the command palette?

Comment: try making it obviously invalid by deleting a `<`

Comment: @SuperCow There is an `XML DOCUMNET ` in the left functional area which below the `OUTLINE` .  If the xml file is invalid, it will show invalidDocument

Comment: @roamer I see the outline in the bottom left of vscode below the workspace, but no `xml document`. Do I need to put a definition of xmltools in `settings`?

Comment: If I make the xml invalid by removing a bracket: no remark by vscode. I can format it with the tool and I have `evaluate xpath` when pressing `f1`

Comment: @Timo Firstly, you need to install XML Tools plugin, xml tree view is default enable. Secondly, open a  XXX.xml file with VS Code. Finally, you will see the `XML DOCUMNET `

Comment: No entry in any menu to validate XML against a XSD schema.

Answer (score 9):

For validation against a schema there is XML extension by Red Hat https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml this no longer requires Java since v0.15.0.

It supports a few ways of associating an `*.xml` with an `*.xsd` or `*.dtd` see the docs at https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/blob/master/docs/Validation.md#validation-with-xsd-grammar

Most methods involve modifying the files or creating a catalog file but you can also associate files using `settings.json`.

###### XSD

```
"xml.fileAssociations": [
   {
       "pattern": "foo.xml",
       "systemId": "foo.xsd"
   }
]
```

###### DTD

```
"xml.fileAssociations": [
  {
      "pattern": "foo.xml",
      "systemId": "foo.dtd"
  }
]
```

File paths support wildcards and VS Code variables `${workspaceFolder}, ${fileDirname}, ${fileBasenameNoExtension}`

Comment: Doesn't work in corporate environnement.